# How do I mount this box without drilling or damaging the shelf?

Tags: installation, product-recommendation, mounting, shelving, adhesive

I bought a network switch that I'd like to hang on the underside of a shelf immediately above my desk. The designers of the switch provides two screw holes on the underside of the box to mount it. Like this; I don't know what this is officially called:

[image]

I'd like to avoid having to permanently mar my shelves in the event I want to reorganize. This leaves mounting tape as an option, but between the weight of the box and the cables pulling down, I'm concerned that the strength of tape/adhesive that I'd need would destroy the finish of the (particleboard) shelf if I have to remove it. Are there any adhesives or ways to mount this box (perhaps a plastic piece that has a screwhead shape that sits flush on the shelf?) that come to mind? I want to avoid finding out the hard way.

Thanks in advance.

edit: Here's pictures of the switch and shelf:

[image]

I'd like to mount it upside down between the two posts.

Comment: Can you include a picture of your shelf? Zip/cable tie come in a variety of size but most residential use one happen to have a head that will slip into the screw mounting slot, this will give you two zip ties sticking out the bottom but opens up some mounting options that you may be able to use.

Comment: Unfortunately the two mounting holes aren't connected internally, otherwise that would have been brilliant to connect to the post like that. Zip ties would be perfect as far as not damaging anything goes

Comment: You didn't get the idea, the female end of the zip tie only goes where a screw head would go so the box will only have a the long male end/tail sticking out. You'd then need to use another zip tie to do anything with it.

Comment: @jason you might loop ONE long zip tie through BOTH holes and run 2 threaded rods between the two shelf standards... and pull the zip tie tight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try these [heavy-duty mounting squares](http://www.staples.com/Scotch-Permanent-Heavy-Duty-Mounting-Squares-1-inch-x-1-inch-16/product_130476)

[image: Heavy duty mounting square]

They're rated for up to 1 lb.  According to [the specs](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122005), your switch weighs 0.6 lbs.

It will fall every time someone trips over a cord, but that is preferable to the whole shelf coming down like with a screw or zip-tie.

Comment: Seems like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can hang a small board between (and hanging of) the posts of the shelf and hang the switch on that

you only need 2 hooks which go in the slots of the posts

Answer (score 0):

It's a Netgear 5-port switch. There's one on my desk exactly like the one you show that I could probably stick to the chewing gun underneath my desk and expect it to stay there indefintely. Weight is not a problem. Even if it did fall, these things are pretty durable.

[Try these Command interlocking strips](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/4421959857640999623?q=Command%20adhesive&safe=active&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.51773540,d.aWM,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jkEW54nYU50.O&biw=1600&bih=1139&tch=1&ech=1&psi=rWguUpf5IpHWrQGBgoHACg.1378773169140.3&sa=X&ei=sGguUqquPMSbqwHGxoC4Cw&ved=0CHgQ8wIwAg). I've hung a full-length mirror from a door with three of them, and the mirror weighs a lot more than that hub. Because they're more or less Velcro, you can remove the hub from the shelf to tinker with it and then stick it back up without needing new strips. They also allow you to place the release tabs completely underneath the hub for a clean look, because you can remove the hub from the shelf to get to the release tabs. And of course, they're Command strips; they're designed to be non-damaging to wall (and shelf) surfaces. Use two just to be sure and don't ever worry about it again.